# calculate the number of atoms in the PDB file

Tags: awk, gawk

I would like to calculate the number of atoms for each residue in the pdb files. A PDB file looks as follows.The third column denotes the atoms and the fourth column denotes the residues.

```
ATOM      1  N   ASN A 380      -0.011  22.902 -13.714  1.00 65.81           N
ATOM      2  CA  ASN A 380       0.401  23.938 -12.714  1.00 65.53           C 
ATOM      3  C   ASN A 380       1.926  24.019 -12.595  1.00 64.48           C
ATOM      9  N   THR A 381       2.553  24.693 -13.562  1.00 61.65           N
ATOM     10  CA  THR A 381       4.006  24.848 -13.609  1.00 58.60           C 
ATOM     16  N   ILE A 382       5.156  22.716 -13.481  1.00 53.48           N  
ATOM     17  CA  ILE A 382       5.808  21.571 -12.830  1.00 49.47           C
ATOM     18  C   ILE A 382       6.645  21.933 -11.584  1.00 45.24           C
ATOM     28  CB  GLN A 383       8.735  24.763 -10.759  1.00 30.19           C 
ATOM     29  CG  GLN A 383      10.140  24.257 -11.037  1.00 29.17           C
ATOM     30  CD  ASN A 384      10.397  23.975 -12.514  1.00 29.51           C
ATOM     31  OE1 ASN A 384      10.892  24.838 -13.237  1.00 30.67           O
```

I would like to get the output as follows

```
Total no:of ASN atoms - 5
Total no:of THR atoms - 2
Total no:of ILE atoms - 3
Total no:of GLN atoms - 2
```

Comment: The PDB format is column oriented, not field oriented. The residue fields are columns 18-20. See the spec at http://www.wwpdb.org/documentation/format33/sect9.html#ATOM . Instead of $4 for the residue name you need to use substr($0, 18, 3). Otherwise you will get the wrong answer for some structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
awk '{print $4}' <file> | sort | uniq -c | \
    awk '{print "Total no:of", $2, "atoms -", $1}'
```

Or pure `awk`:

```
awk '{atom[$4]++;}
    END{for (i in atom) {print "Total no:of", i, "atoms -", atom[i]} }' <file>
```

Output for both methods:

```
Total no:of GLN atoms - 2
Total no:of THR atoms - 2
Total no:of ASN atoms - 5
Total no:of ILE atoms - 3
```